# Performance of 2D scrolling options in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I recently reviewed the tutorial on 2D scrolling backgrounds in Unity here: 
http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/2d-scrolling-backgrounds

The author presents two models for scrolling backgrounds, and as far as I can tell, they are equivalent in terms of the output.  However, they are implemented differently.

1) adjust the transform of the sprite over time to move it across the screen.

2) create a quad for your background, apply a texture to it, and adjust the offset of the applied texture

Given the output being the same in terms of user experience, the obvious question for me that remains unanswered is, which has the lower cost then in terms of performance?

Comment: Premature optimization. Probably negligible. Certainly won't be a "make or break" kind of difference. Also performance characteristics of such things always depend on the target platform to some degree, sometimes to a large degree, so it can not be answered definitely.

Comment: sounds good.  Cocos2D evangelist answering a Unity question?  I won't tell the others.

Comment: I happen to be using Unity regularly, too. In my defense: I'm not enjoying it nearly as much. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Should be fine either way. Go with whatever is easier for you, but keep in mind the alternative. You could use both and switch between the two to optimize framerate, but I have a feeling it would be wasted effort.